# Limited performance with use of permutation and recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, permutation, repeat

I'm writing a program that calculates the longest streak weighted by their probability and is using recursion to obtain all different possible scenarios. This is the coding challenge that I'm doing: https://open.kattis.com/problems/winningstreak

I noticed that the permutation function that I have is not the most effective when it comes to larger input due to recursion. An example input would be 3 and it would add the following to the matches array:
000, 010, 001, 011, 100,110,101,111

```
public static void Permutations(string text, int numberOfGames,     List<String> matches)
    {
        if (numberOfGames > 0)
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                Permutations(text + j.ToString(), numberOfGames - 1, matches);
        else
        {
            matches.Add(text.ToString());
        }

    }
```

My problem lies with larger inputs (example 500), since that causes crashes on my program and throws the error: Garbage collector could not allocate 16384 bytes of memory for major heap section.
Is there any other way to improve this recursion so it runs better on larger inputs?

Thank you guys!

Comment: You should add details describing the exception+stack you encounter.

Comment: For this question to be on topic here, you need to tell us where your program crashes, and what "larger inputs" cause it to crash.

Comment: 3000 games per season.. that rocks

Comment: It's the permutation algorithm that crashes.  Example of an input could be 500 and a probability of whatever, let's say 0.4.

Comment: Hint: recursion can often be replaced with iteration.

Comment: @AlexK. I think I explained it better now, sorry for before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My problem lies with larger inputs (example 500)

Your program attempts to produce a list with 2<sup>500</sup> strings.

There are roughly 2<sup>267</sup> atoms in the universe.

I find it unsurprising that you're running out of memory.

Find a more clever solution to your problem.

Remember, the problem is not "enumerate all possible combinations of games".  The problem is to deduce the expected value of the length of the longest streak. Generating all possible combinations and summing up the length of the longest streak in each is not going to work when the number of combinations becomes large.

Also remember that the statement of the problem is that the result *must be within some fraction of the exact result*. It does not have to be the exact result. Use meta-reasoning when dealing with puzzles like this: the person who posed the puzzle likely would not have made that relaxation of the problem unless it was something you could take advantage of.

Does this give you some insight into how to solve the problem?

If you want some more hints and insight, start by reading this:

http://gato-docs.its.txstate.edu/mathworks/DistributionOfLongestRun.pdf